# MavensMate/Sublime Text - how to investigate schema

Tags: schema, tools

I'm going through an evaluation of MavensMate and Sublime Text as a replacement of Eclipse IDE. Everything is working well and is a great alternative to Eclipse which is clunky and slow.

The main thing I'm missing is a schema explorer to play with SOQL queries and find field developernames. I know I can use the SFDC 'Schema Builder' but it doesn't cover behind the scenes tables like RecordType, OpportunityLineItem etc...

What tools are recommended by the community?

Comment: Look at: https://force-cli.heroku.com/

Answer (score 10):

On the Mac, my favorite tool is SoqlXplorer:

http://www.pocketsoap.com/osx/soqlx/

Comment: Impressed by this one. Thanks for the heads-up.

Comment: @greenstork while you are listing the tools also please note that there are lot of windows users as well.

Answer (score 8):

Another fantastic one in the toolkit is [workbench](http://workbench.developerforce.com).  Lots of admin tools, including the ability to explore all standard (even the behind the scenes ones) and custom object.

Also good to have a bookmark to the [Object Reference](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/object_reference/index.htm) handy.

Answer (score 2):

As a couple of alternatives to workbench (which I'd also recommend)

---

On Windows you can use the [FuseIT SFDC Explorer](http://www.fuseit.com/Solutions/SFDC-Explorer/Help-SOQL-Queries.aspx)* to get the API names for sObjects and compose SOQL queries.

* This falls into the shameless self promotion category as I work for the company that makes it. Still it is free, and it can be good to have alternatives.

[image: FuseIT SFDC Explorer]

---

There is also the [Force.com Explorer](http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/ForceExplorer) which is AIR based.

---

The [Force.com CLI](http://blogs.developerforce.com/developer-relations/2013/11/announcing-the-command-line-interface-for-force-com.html)

> />force sobject list

Answer (score 2):

For those running on a Mac, [soqlXplorer](http://www.pocketsoap.com/osx/soqlx) is a great tool for doing these kind of things. You can run queries easily and then update data in the database by just editing the result rows.

Answer (score 0):

I am building a Force.com web IDE. Still in Beta.

**Functionality:**

```
Create new Apex Triggers Classes, Visualforce Pages & Components
Select from a list of predefined templates to create class stubs
Code debugger
Run Anonymous Apex Code
Run SOQL queries
Run Batch queries
Metadata viewer and download
Code Metrics Dashboard
```

**Try it out:**
[http://cloudsole.com](http://cloudsole-developer.herokuapp.com/)