# Where to see salesforce.schema in Mavensmate?

Tags: mavensmate

As a regular user of eclipse i am using Mavensmate in parallel to get comfortable with that environment. So far, it has been a nice experience while working with Mavensmate. While working with it, i am trying to locate salesforce.schema as we usually do in eclipse where we can see schema, relationship, fields, etc. Where to see salesforce.schema in Mavensmate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no schema  builder/editor in Mavensmate.Please post your question related to Mavensmate [here](https://github.com/joeferraro/MavensMate/issues?page=1&state=open) in GitHub.

You could use workbench for soql builder

Also found another post related to your question.

[MavensMate/Sublime Text - how to investigate schema](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/21653/mavensmate-sublime-text-how-to-investigate-schema)